# how to remain max column in groupby table?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I made summarized table like below using pandas groupby function

|  | I | II |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | apple | 3 |
|  | banana | 4 |
| B | dog | 1 |
|  | cat | 2 |
| C | seoul | 9 |
|  | tokyo | 5 |

I want to remain if II column has max value in each category.
For example, in A category I want to remain banana row only because it has max value in II column.
the result table what I want to get is like below.

|  | I | II |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | banana | 4 |
| B | cat | 2 |
| C | seoul | 9 |

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dataframe used by me:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'II': {('A', 'apple'): 3,
  ('A', 'banana'): 4,
  ('B', 'dog'): 1,
  ('B', 'cat'): 2,
  ('C', 'seoul'): 9,
  ('C', 'tokyo'): 5}})
```

Try via `sort_values()`,`reset_index()` and `drop_duplicates()`:

```
out=(df.sort_values('II',ascending=False)
   .reset_index()
   .drop_duplicates('level_0')
   .set_index('level_0')
   .rename_axis(index=None)
   .rename(columns={'level_1':'I'}))
```

**OR**

```
out=(df.reset_index()
       .sort_values('II',ascending=False)
       .groupby('level_0')
       .first()
       .rename(columns={'level_1':'I'})
       .rename_axis(index=None))
```

output of `out`:

```
    I       II
C   seoul   9
A   banana  4
B   cat     2
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. however it is not working for me. could you explain what is the role of 'level_0'?

Comment: Thank you. I solved my problem using your answer.
out=df.sort_values('II',ascending=False).reset_index().drop_duplicates(subset='category')
* I gave index column name as 'category

Comment: @JihoonSeo updated answer....kindly have a look ***:)***

Comment: @JihoonSeo when you use `reset_index()` on a MultiIndexed Dataframe then it's consicutive level becomes columns and they are named according to their level..so here `'level_0'` is the column name assign to the 0th level of MultiIndex

Comment: okay now I understand what is role of 'level_0'. thank you for your kindly reply :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the most elegant solution, but if you want this should work with a `groupby` object.

```
# Creating the Dummy DataFrame
d = {
'Letter': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'], 'Word': ['apple', 'banana', 
    'dog', 'cat', 'seoul', 'tokyo'], 'II': [3, 4, 1, 2, 9, 5]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df_max = df.groupby('Letter')[['II']].agg('max')

df_max = df_max.merge(df, how='left', on='II') # merge the "Word" column back into df_max
```

You could then reorder the columns if you need them to be in a specific order.